# Show that $Y^2-X^3\mid f$ if $f$ vanishes on the curve $C: (t^2,t^3)$, and determine what property of a field $k$ will ensure that the result holds.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, parametric

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R^1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ be the map given by $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$; prove directly that any polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ vanishing on the image $C=\phi(\mathbb{R^1})$ is divisible by $Y^2-X^3$.

Determine that property of a field $k$ will ensure that the result holds for $\phi: k\rightarrow k^2$ given by the same formula.

Here is how I did the first part:

By division algorithm, I can write

$$f(X,Y)=(Y^2-X^3)f_1(X,Y)+Yf_2(X)+f_3(X)$$

Since $f(t^2,t^3)=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we have, for all $t$,

$$t^3f_2(t^2)+f_3(t^2)=0$$

Comparing the odd and even power terms of $t$ gives

$$f_2(X)=f_3(X)=0$$ This shows $f$ is divisible by $Y^2-X^3$.

I am not sure how to do the second part though. It seems to me the argument could work for all fields, unless the division algorithm fails. But when does it fail? Or will the odd and even power argument fail at some point?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need something in the implication $\forall t\in k, t^3f_2(t^2)+f_3(t^2)=0 \Rightarrow X^3f_2(X^2)+f_3(X^2)=0$.

Comment: @user113969: Sorry, aren't they exactly the same?

Comment: @KittyL Just because a polynomial evaluates to $0$ at all points does not mean it's the zero polynomial. It does in some fields, though, and that's what user113969 is after.

Comment: @KittyL No they are not. By $X^3f_2(X^2)+f_3(X^2)$ I mean the polynomial in $k[X]$ not the associated function...

Comment: @user113969: I see. Thank you so much for the answer. I have another question then. Does it mean the characteristic of the field has to be zero? Or the field has to be infinite? Or are these two statements the same?

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @KittyL It is sufficient that the field is infinite. Being of characteristic zero implies that the field is infinite, but the converse does not hold (take $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$.

Comment: @user113969: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out, a sufficient condition is taking the ground field to be infinite. This can be traced back to the following very general considerations: if $f\in A[(X_i)_{i\in I}]$ is a polynomial ($A$ a commutative ring), then we get an induced map $\tilde{f}:A^I\rightarrow A$ obtained by substitution. It turns out that the map $f\mapsto\tilde{f}$ is injective whenever $A$ is an infinite integral domain (e.g. a field).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. This sounds like an interesting generalization. Since it seems much beyond what I have learned on this topic so far, I'm wondering if the proof is very involved?

Comment: @KittyL: it is not so involved, nothing serious. it is mainly formal, you can find it in Bourbaki's algebra, chapter 5.